# How to correctly fan out a list in CompletableFutures

Tags: java, spring, completable-future

I'm trying to fan out from a method which returns a `CompletableFuture<List>` into another method for each list element, where the fan in turn also returns a `CompletableFuture` each. Afterwards i want to return a `CompletableFuture.allOf` from the Futures produced by the list.

In essence i have the following methods (assume they are in their own Service classes, i just combined them for brevity here):

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<List<File>> getMatchingCsvFrom(Path directory, Pattern pattern) {
    ...some work here
}

@Async
public CompletableFuture<Boolean> processSingleCsv(File csvFile) {
    ...some work here
}
```

And i'm trying to call them like this:

```
public CompletableFuture<Void> processDirectory(Path directory) {
    CompletableFuture<List<File>> matchingCsvFrom = fileProcessingService.getMatchingCsvFrom(directory, PROCESS_PATTERN);

    List<CompletableFuture<Boolean>> processFutures = matchingCsvFrom.get().stream()
            .map(file -> processService.processProcessCsv(file))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return CompletableFuture.allOf(processFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));
}
```

The `.get()` is obviously a problem there, but i'm not able to resolve it using `.thenApply()`, `.thenAccept()`, or `.thenCompose()`.

Unfortunately all other answers i found want to accomplish the opposite (going from `List<CompletableFuture>` to `CompletableFuture<List>`). Appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
public CompletableFuture<Void> processDirectory(Path directory) {
    CompletableFuture<List<File>> matchingCsvFrom = fileProcessingService.getMatchingCsvFrom(directory, PROCESS_PATTERN);

    return matchingCsvFrom.thenCompose( list -> {
        var processFutures = list.stream()
            .map(file -> processService.processProcessCsv(file))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]);
        return CompletableFuture.allOf(processFutures);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried something similar with `thenCompose()`, but i missed that it always has to return a `CompletableFuture`.